# Are my formulas correct?

Tags: r, regression, t-test, p-value, linear

This is an incredibly stupid question, but I've found it so hard to find any consistent information on this. I'm trying to calculate a t test for linear regression using R. Here are my formulas:

```
SSy <-  sum((y - mean(y))^2)
SSxy <-  sum((x - mean(x)) * (y - mean(y)))
SSR <-  sum((y - mean(y))^2)
SSE <-  sum((y - yhat)^2)
SSTO <-  SSR + SSE
MSE <- sum((y - yhat)^2) / (n - 2)

b1 <- SSxy / SSx
se <- sqrt(MSE) / sqrt(SSx)
t <- b1 / se
p <- 2 * pt(-abs(t), df = n - 1)
```

My only problem is, is that my t value seems wrong.
It's -25.21. And, my p value seems very wrong, it's 1.271e-34.

Thank you

Comment: In a cases like this, the strategy would be to (a) write out the formulas, (b) check the code against the formulas, (c) find a fully worked example and check each calculation in order. However your df for the t-test is wrong. Where are you getting your formulas from?

Comment: One way to check your results is to use  R: `mod <- lm( ... )`, `summary(mod)`

Comment: @Glen_b, I got my formula for "p <- ..." from an article I found on medium. Maybe I misinterpreted it. 

But, isn't n - 1 the correct amount of degrees of freedom since I'm dealing with a 1 sample t-test?

Comment: @kjetil b halvorsen, I check my results using the code you recommended. Thank you!

Comment: No it's not a one sample t-test but a test for a regression coefficient. With a one sample t you lose one df by estimating one parameter for the mean, but here you're estimating two parameters. I'd suggest finding a good book on statistics (one that covers regression), so you're not mixing formulas across different applications.

Comment: @Glen_b So in the case of a t-test for a regression coefficient, am I correct to say that I'm using b1 & se to estimate the two parameters the t-test needs to test the null hypothesis?

Comment: The two parameters are the intercept and slope parameters in a simple regression (whether you explicitly calculated both or not, that's the model you're fitting); they both impact the distribution of the mean square error (MSE <- sum((y - yhat)^2) / (n - 2)) and hence the *denominator* of the t-statistic and that is where its degrees of freedom come from.